# Error using Keras callback_tensorboard

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using R 3.2.3, Keras 2.1.6, and TensorFlow 1.10 for a text classification problem. I am trying to set up instrumentation via TensorBoard, but I'm stuck on this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: To visualize embeddings, embeddings_data must be provided.
```

Here's my minimal model/training setup:

```
# x, y, and tokens loaded from tab files
num_samples <- 30000L
train_sample <- sample(1:dim(x)[1], num_samples)

tb_log <- "tb_log"
tensorboard(tb_log)

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_embedding(input_dim = dim(tokens)[1], output_dim = 128, input_length = 1000) %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 7, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 5) %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 7, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_global_max_pooling_1d() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

summary(model)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("acc")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  x[train_sample,], y[train_sample],
  epochs = 3,
  batch_size = 128,
  validation_split = 0.5,
  callbacks = c(callback_tensorboard(
    log_dir = tb_log,
    embeddings_freq = 1,
    histogram_freq = 1
  ))
)
```

The model trains for the first epoch, then the process terminates with the above error. If I remove the `callbacks` option from the `fit` call, the model trains and works as expected. There is no `embeddings_data` argument for the callback that I can see. I've tried passing in `embeddings_metadata` as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/embedding), but I still get the same error. If I just remove the `embedding_freq` option from the callback, I get this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'embedding_10_input' with dtype float and shape [?,1000]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

**update**

The second error (`InvalidArgumentError`) is apparently caused by some corruption of the environment after trying to use the callback with `embeddings_freq` set. If I remove that option, delete the logs folder, and restart my R session from scratch, I can get it to train and produce histograms, etc, but still no dice on visualizing actual embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been down to a version mismatch between TensorFlow, the python Keras module, and the R Keras module. For someone trying to troubleshoot this in the future, you can check all three versions like so:

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"
python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"
Rscript -e "library(keras); sessionInfo()"
```

Or `python3 -c ...` as the case may be. It's also important that your R environment is using the right Python environment, which you can check with:

```
Rscript -e "reticulate::py_config()"
```

Beyond that it's a little bit of trial and error; I haven't found anything that consistently documents which Keras versions support which TensorFlow versions, etc. For my situation the magic nexus ended up being TensorFlow `1.10` built for Python `2.7.2`, and Keras `2.2`.